# На каком алгоритме лучше основывать выдачу результатов (кроме PR)?

Tags: алгоритм, веб-программирование, seo

**Делаю поисковик.**

**Делать аналог PR не хочу ищу альтернативы**

Вопрос в том, что, по-вашему мнению, лучше алгоритма PR (в виде основного критерия формирования результатов)?
Какие есть альтернативы (в виде основного критерия формирования результатов)? 
Нестандартные алгоритмы (в виде основного критерия формирования результатов).

Мои варианты:

1. Анализировать количество закладок на страницу в браузере пользователя (чем больше, тем выше результат в поиске).
   PR-основывается на том, сколько сайтов ссылается на данный сайт. Чем больше, тем выше сайт в результатах.
2. Очень жёстко анализировать html. Вплоть до цвета фона странички.

Просьба отвечать по существу вопроса. )
Т. е. я понимаю, что сейчас очень много факторов при ранжировании, но интересует именно основной фактор, сейчас это повсеместно аналоги PR + пытаются внедрять машинное обучение. 
Ясное дело, что анализ самого html тоже будет применяться.

Answer (score 1):

1. Вообще не пользуюсь встроенными в браузер закладками.
2. Цвет фона не имеет никакого отношения к содержанию страницы. Что делать если я вдруг решил поставить свой CSS?

   Основная проблема поисковиков, не в алгоритме(он по сути один, составить индекс роботом в одном месте, обработать запрос в другом -> так или иначе отсортировать результаты), а в том что нужно дофига физических стоек вместе с системам охлаждения, пожаротушения, бесперебойного питания и прочими админскими радостями для нормального хранения и составления индекса.

   Выдача результатов во всех существующих поисковиках далека от идеала и они крайне назойливы. Например факт, что GMail почта небезопасна, так как Google без спроса парсит текст ваших писем внутри и потом не смущаясь выдает контекстную рекламу основываясь на их содержании.

   Ранжирование имеет смысл проводить эвристически, рассчитывая как-можно больше объективных показателей для каждого домена и документа и потом на их основании выставлять общую оценку каким-нибудь статистическим методом. Навряд ли существует какой-то волшебный главный критерий повозляющий определить чем одна страничка на каком-то хосте на чьей-то кухне, лучше миллиона остальных.

Comment: Кстати алгоритмов много! Особенно если шерстить буржунет и есть достаточно таки удачные .